# Background Black color showing in circular Imageview

Tags: android

I have designed circularimageview when I run the application and I am facing issues with black background around the circular image in my layout, How to fix this issue.

xml file

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/gs_image_userProfileimage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#95c764"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"

            app:civ_shadow_radius="3" />
```

Java coding:

```
 gs_image_userProfileimage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.gs_image_userProfileimage);

     Picasso.with(getContext())
      .load(gs_var_userimage)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.getspot_logo)
       .into(gs_image_userProfileimage);
```

I tried to give setLayout (view.Layout_Hardware) even though its showing the same thing.

Comment: Can you paste screen-shot?

Comment: I added the screen-shot

Comment: post full xml..

Comment: Have you given try with Glide instead of Picasso?

Comment: If I use glide first time its not loading when I go some menus then I give back its working.,first time why its not loading

Answer (score 2):

You can simple set the background color of circular ring.

```
app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/blue_background"
```

Comment: Although. it did not solve my problem. But your answer gave me clue to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the imageview type as `CircleImageView`

It should be declared as

`de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView gs_image_userProfileimage;`

then use like this

```
gs_image_userProfileimage=(de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.gs_image_userProfileimage);
gs_image_userProfileimage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: if its lollipop try this `gs_image_userProfileimage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`, see updated answer

Comment: Yes but I don't know why its showing still,Problem in Picasso?? If i use glide image not showing first time

Comment: not possibly because of picasso, have you tried all three `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`,`LAYER_TYPE_NONE `,`LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE `

Comment: if still not working try wrapping the `CircleImageView` in a linearlayout and assign `setLayerType` to the linear layout

Comment: LinearLayout laylinear=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.laylinear);
       
        laylinear.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        laylinear.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        laylinear.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
right?? same issue

Answer (score 1):

define your image view background like below code ..

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/gs_image_userProfileimage"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#95c764"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="3" />
```

change only this

```
    android:background="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a View or Layout widget behind the Circular Image then you must set the Tint to transparent like so:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
     android:id="@+id/gs_image_userProfileimage"
     android:layout_width="80dp"
     android:layout_height="80dp"
     app:civ_border_color="#95c764"
     app:civ_border_width="2dp"
     android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
     app:civ_shadow_radius="3" />
```

Example:
[image: The Problem]

[image: Fixed]